# Exemplary open-source Spring projects

Tags: spring

I am new to the Spring Framework. With Spring Core course recently taken, what would be some good example projects to download and learn good design from?

Perfect would be a well designed project, small enough to read through and understand, big enough to have a structure that can scale well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring ships with a very comprehensive example application called PetClinic. It was originally inspired by the PetStore J2EE example application, demonstrating just how much easier things were in Spring.

This is intended to represent "best practice" for Spring development. You can find it in the distribution package.

Answer (score 1):

Spring distribution has the samples which are very good to start with. The petclinic application is where I start with.